# Google Analytics - View data not showing

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, analytics

I am sorting the analytics for my website (Wordpress Network in subdirectories not subdomains) and I am currently tracking all incoming visits to the website absolutely fine.

However we have several basic views we wish to create for the subdirectory microsites:

www.example.com/press

www.example.com/global

www.example.com/us

www.example.com/careers

When I duplicate the existing analytics view (which works fine) it creates a new view, with exactly the same settings, that then shows that we have never had a single person on our site ever.

Until these new views show the overall incoming data, I can't filter it down to show just traffic to the subdirectory.

I hope someone else has experienced the same issue, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Views start empty, data shows up as it is collected. So this will take a few hours (at least four, at worst 48). You should see data in the realtime view, but historical data will not show up in a new view. Plus this is not code-related and quite possibly off-topic.

Comment: Apologies if this is off-topic, I've just resolved many other analytics issues using Stack Overflow in the past.

These views were set up prior to me leaving before Christmas and didn't record any visits over the break. Yet when I look at my overall web stats I can see there has definitely been traffic to the sub directories. Rather odd.